# Pow(3.0,3.0)!=27.0

Tags: java, android

Вместо 27.0 Math.pow(3.0,3.0) возвращает 26.999999999999993. В чем проблема?

Comment: Ошибка стандарта  IEEE 754 - двоичные вычисления с плавающей точкой

Answer (score 2):

Это не проблема, а вполне допустимое поведение. Дело в том,  что множество действительных чисел не только бесконечно, но и непрерывно, поэтому, сколько бы мы не взяли бит, мы неизбежно столкнемся с числами, которые не имеют точного представления.

Поэтому вы получаете достаточно точный ответ, который близок к 27.0

Comment: Не согласен. Это проблема, которую нужно учитывать и научиться обходить. Тут-то ладно, а как быть бухгалтерам, у которых баланс падает из-за такого "допустимого поведения"?

Comment: У каждого решения есть свои границы применимости и свои ограничения. Числа с плавающей запятой позволяют представлять достаточно большое подмножество действительных чисел, от 10^−308 до 10^308, но за это приходится платить точностью. Если же у вас чисто бухгалтерская задача, в которой числа строго десятичные, с двумя знаками после запятой, то, очевидно, это решание вам не подходит и надо использовать другое.

Comment: Я комментировал Ваш ответ. У меня нет такой задачи, а о стандарте написал еще в первом комментарии.

Comment: Почему тогда pow(9.0,1.5) возвращает 27.0?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/ На доступно Хабре расписывали. Коротко: ошибка может появиться, а может и не появиться. Не случайно, зависит от значений и операций над ними

Comment: @vikttur для бухгалтеров используйте `BigDecimal`. Особенности double широко известны. И как сказал @akashihi ```если это решение вам не подходит то надо использовать другое```, а не учится обходить.

Comment: Я писал о ом, что нужно знать и учитывать возможность ошибки. *И спользовать другое* - это один из способов "*обходить*".